# KL and JS Divergence analysis of PDFs of numbers

Tags: python, numpy, probability, probability-density, probability-distribution

I am playing around with divergence metrics, and I found that if I implement the calculations on my own or rely on the built-in libs, I get two different numbers. Now, I don't know what am (is) I (the built-in function) doing wrong.

For simple analysis, I came up with the following toy example in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#two arrays of "events"
p=np.array([1,2,2,3,5,4,2,3,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,4,2,3,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,4,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,5,4,2,2,1,2,2,3])
q=np.array([2,3,2,4,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,5,4,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,4,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,5,4])
```

I was told that since I will be comparing the two PDF and calculating divergence metrics for them, the "sample space" for each of them should be the same. Hence, I take all possible values taken by both `p` and `q` and use that to calculate the PDFs.
This is my simple function to calculate PDF for an array of data in an array of sample space:

```
def create_prob_dist(data: np.array, sample_space: np.array):
  #number of all events
  sum_of_events = sample_space.size
  #get the counts of each event via pandas.crosstab()
  data_counts = pd.crosstab(index='counts', columns=data)
  
  #create probabilities for each event
  prob_dist=dict()

  for i in sample_space:
    if i in data_counts:
      prob_dist[i]=(data_counts[i]['counts'])/sum_of_events
    else: 
      prob_dist[i]=0

  return prob_dist
```

To calculate the PDFs with the function, I do these steps:

```
#get all possible discrete events from p and q
px=np.array(list(set(p))) #we use set here to remove duplicates
qx=np.array(list(set(q))) #we use set here to remove duplicates

#create all possible discrete events of both p and q
mx=np.concatenate([px,qx]) #concatenate first
mx=np.array(list(set(mx))) #remove duplicates
mx.sort() #then sort


#create true PDFs of p and q using mx
p_pdf=create_prob_dist(p, mx)
q_pdf=create_prob_dist(q, mx)

#get the probability values only from the dictionary
p_pdf=np.array(list(p_pdf.values()))
q_pdf=np.array(list(q_pdf.values()))
```

Then, I can plot the PDFs and the results are in line with my expectations:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(mx, q_pdf, 'g', label="Q")
plt.plot(mx, p_pdf, 'r', label="P")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image: PDF of p and q]

So, once I have the PDFs and also view them, I have a sense of what I would expect from a divergence calculation. In fact, in this case, we should expect something much closer to 0 than 1.

### KL divergence

I followed the equation of KL divergence as this:

[image: KL divergence metric]

Accordingly, I created this simple function:

```
def KL_divergence(P:np.array, Q: np.array):
  KL=0
  for i,x in enumerate(P):
    if ((Q[i] != 0) and (x != 0)): #avoid dividing with 0 and avoid having 0 in math.log()
        KL += x * math.log(x / Q[i])
  return KL
```

Note, in my case, P and Q are already prepared well (meaning they were calculated with the same sample space)

I compared my calculation with built-in functions:

```
from scipy.special import kl_div,rel_entr
print("KL divergence of p and q       : {}".format(KL_divergence(p_pdf,q_pdf)))
kl_divergence=kl_div(p_pdf,q_pdf)
print("KL divergence (lib) of p and q : {}".format(sum(kl_divergence)))
print("KL divergence (lib2) of p and q: {}".format(sum(rel_entr(p_pdf, q_pdf))))
```

and I get the following output:

```
KL divergence of p and q       : 0.4900499180923177
KL divergence (lib) of p and q : 0.09004991809231755
KL divergence (lib2) of p and q: 0.4900499180923177
```

The rel_entr() gives the same metric as mine, but the kl_div() gives something totally different.

What do you think? Which one is the right one and why?

### JS divergence

Since JS divergence is a normalized/balanced version of KL divergence, I also calculated that and compared it to built-in functions.
I found two slightly different definitions. One is just doing a bi-directional KL divergence comparison and getting the average.
The other one, from Wikipedia, uses a mixture distribution as well described as
[image: JS divergence]

Accordingly, I have the following implementations for JS (using my KL functions)

```
#the simple JS
def JS_divergence(P:np.array, Q:np.array):
  KL_P_Q=KL_divergence(P, Q)
  KL_Q_P=KL_divergence(Q, P)

  JS=(KL_P_Q+KL_Q_P)/2
  return JS   

# Wikipedia version
def mod_JS_divergence(P:np.array, Q:np.array):
  #create M
  M=(P+Q)/2 #sum the two distributions then get average

  KL_P_Q=KL_divergence(P, M)
  KL_Q_P=KL_divergence(Q, M)

  JS=(KL_P_Q+KL_Q_P)/2
  return JS
```

And this is the code to get the results, which include the use of the built-in function too.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import jensenshannon
print("JS divergence of p and q       : {}".format(JS_divergence(p_pdf,q_pdf)))
print("mod JS divergence of p and q   : {}".format(mod_JS_divergence(p_pdf,q_pdf)))

js_divergence=jensenshannon(p_pdf,q_pdf)
print("JS divergence (lib) of p and q : {}".format(js_divergence))
```

output:

```
JS divergence of p and q       : 0.08763662020764684
mod JS divergence of p and q   : 0.021872274274735898
JS divergence (lib) of p and q : 0.041044079757403054
```

I am more concerned now about my JS divergence calculations as none of my functions return the same outcome as the built-in one.

My question is again the same: what am I doing wrong? what is the way the built-in function differs from my calculations? Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: For the KL divergence, scipy's `rel_entr` is the function you want to use. If you read the notes in [`kl_div`'s documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.kl_div.html), you'll see they mention using a nonstandard formula.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. So, at least, my calculation is correct and in line with `rel_entr()`. 
But then, regarding the JS divergence, is it possible that the built-in function is based on the nonstandard `kl_div`?

Comment: No, it uses `rel_entr`. You're getting different results for 2 reasons: your pdf arrays need to be normalized, and scipy's definition of JS distance is `sqrt(mod JS divergence)`. You'll find the same results as scipy by computing: `np.sqrt(mod_JS_divergence(p_pdf/p_pdf.sum(),q_pdf/q_pdf.sum()))`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for pointing this out. I am not far to be an expert in probability theory, so could you explain or point me to the right literature:
why must the pdfs be normalized?

Comment: @Seon: btw., I also used the divergence calculations the real data I wanted them for. I have one million integer numbers in my dataset (ranging from 1 to ~4 billion). In this case, my KL divergence functions return: `-0.2047978490479795`, while both built-in functions return: `inf`
the JS numbers (after your suggestions) are interestingly the same (`0.6763192318731195`).

Comment: In discrete cases, if f is the pdf of X, f(k) := Pr(X=k). The sum of probabilities over all events is 1, which is why your pdfs should sum to 1 (aka be normalized). The `create_prob_dist` function is incorrect, and should be returning normalized arrays.

Comment: so, I think i mixed up the variables in my `create_prob_dist function`. Instead of 
`sum_of_events = sample_space.size`, it should be: `sum_of_events = data.size
`. Then, the pdf.sum() returns 1. Then, I won't need to normalize the PDFs again for my `mod_JS_divergence()` just need to take the `sqrt` of it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Seon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13145954/seon) for the help. Accordingly, the problem is solved:

```
def create_prob_dist(data: np.array, sample_space: np.array):
  #number of all events
  sum_of_events = data.size #REPLACED sample_space.size to get normalized PDFs
  #get the counts of each event via pandas.crosstab()
  data_counts = pd.crosstab(index='counts', columns=data)
  
  #create probabilities for each event
  prob_dist=dict()

  for i in sample_space:
    if i in data_counts:
      prob_dist[i]=(data_counts[i]['counts'])/sum_of_events
    else: 
      prob_dist[i]=0

  return prob_dist
```

Accordingly, the PDF plot is correct by having the appropriate `y` axis below `1.0`.
[image: PDF plot with correct y axis]

Correcting the JS divergence function via adding np.sqrt() to the return value

```
# Wikipedia version
def mod_JS_divergence(P:np.array, Q:np.array):
  #create M
  M=(P+Q)/2 #sum the two distributions then get average

  KL_P_Q=KL_divergence(P, M)
  KL_Q_P=KL_divergence(Q, M)

  JS=(KL_P_Q+KL_Q_P)/2
  return np.sqrt(JS)
```

The results are fine now and are the same:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import jensenshannon
print("JS divergence of p and q       : {}".format(JS_divergence(p_pdf,q_pdf)))
print("mod JS divergence of p and q   : {}".format(mod_JS_divergence(p_pdf,q_pdf)))
```

output:

```
mod JS divergence of p and q   : 0.04104407975740311
JS divergence (lib) of p and q : 0.0410440797574027
```